# Accessing images from remote or external resource in jsp

Tags: image, jsp, servlets

I am trying to implement a web page where images location is outside my web application.
I will iterate through the images folder and then load the images in jsp.

But when i do it everything works fine but images are not displaying.
I found the reason too, its prepends application context to image location.
For example if my image location is "d:/images", when the img src is resolves, the path becomes http: // hostname //portnumber/exampled/d:/images/image1.gif

Following is my code.

Service class:

```
public List<String> getSiteKeyImages(){
    List<String> imageList = new ArrayList<String>();
    File directory = new File(PropertyFileReader.getNycbMessage().getProperty("imageURL"));
    if(directory.isDirectory()){
        String[] images = directory.list();
        for(String image:images){
            imageList.add(image);
        }
    }
    return imageList;
}
```

servlet class:

```
private List<String> images = new ArrayList<String>();
images = userService.getSiteKeyImages();
session.setAttribute("images",images);
```

Then my jsp page code is

```
<div id = "pamImages">
    <ul class="thumbs noscript">
    <c:forEach items="${images}" var="image">
    <li>
        <a id="${image}" class="thumb" name="leaf" href="javascript: selected_image('${image}')">
        <img src="${CONFIG_URL}${image}" height="50" width="50"></td>
        </a>
    </li>
  </c:forEach>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Ca anyone tell me what wrong i am doing here.

Comment: this is because you are using ${CONFIG_URL} instead of d:images which may not be having any value

Comment: ${CONFIG_URL} value is being picked from property file and its value is = d:/images/, then i append with image name to it.

Comment: what values you are getting in $images and $confi_url alert them may be you not getting the correct path

Comment: @user1834664 put the images in your project folder